# Trying to get property of non-object laravel 5 - What is my mistake?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is my mistake?

Employeecontroller :

```
public function index()
{
  $employees = Employee::all();
  return view('employee.view_all_employee_details', compact('employees'));
}
```

Employee Model function :

```
protected $primaryKey = "emp_id";
protected $with = 'additionaldetails';
public function additionaldetails()
{
 return $this->hasOne('App/EmployeeAdditionalDetail' , 'emp_id' , 'emp_id');
}
```

EmployeeAdditionalDetail model :

```
public function employeeDetails()
{
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee' , 'emp_id' , 'emp_id');
}
```

view_all_employee_details View

```
@if(count($employees) > 0)

@foreach($employees as $employee)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $employee->first_name }} </td>
        <td> {{ $employee->manager_id }} </td>
        <td>

          {{ $employee->additionaldetails->emp_id }}  **Error showing here**
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

@else
   {!! "<tr><td>No Recod Found</td></tr>" !!}

@endif
```

MyError:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{{ $employee->additionaldetails->emp_id }}
```

Employee model has access to basicdetails() function. You are trying to get data using additionaldetails().

also change this line

```
return $this->hasOne('App/EmployeeAdditionalDetail' , 'emp_id' , 'emp_id');
```

to

```
return $this->hasOne('App\EmployeeAdditionalDetail' , 'emp_id' , 'emp_id');
```

Comment: also in Employee model `protected $with = 'additionaldetails';` should be `protected $with = array('basicdetails');`

Comment: thanks shuvrow. I have changed to {{ $employee->basicdetails->emp_id }}. But still same problem.

Comment: @Slow loris.thanks. But still facing same problem. :(

Comment: plz provide the output of $employee->additionaldetails

Comment: @sankaran please go over the edits on this answer and your question, modify your code accordingly and try again, it should work.